Has the architecture of rmw_zenoh for ROS shifted from C to C++?
I have been following the development of the rmw_zenoh implementation for ROS 2, and I noticed some significant updates in recent releases. Originally, the project aimed to implement an RMW (ROS Middleware) layer written in C to interface with Zenoh, which itself had a C-based implementation.
However, it now appears that rmw_zenoh has shifted to a C++ implementation (rmw_zenoh_cpp) with dependencies on Zenoh's C++ bindings (zenoh_cpp_vendor).
Why was the transition made from a C-based RMW layer to a C++ implementation?
What are the expected benefits with this new C++ based approach compared to the original C implementation?

A good question, but I think that https://discourse.ros.org/ is a better place to ask this kind of rather none technical questions.
